# Rename tick marks on x-axis in spaghetti plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am quite new to R and I am trying to create a spaghetti plot to compare in 4 groups the percentage of patients taking rescue medication, at different timepoints (1 hour after surgery, 4 hours, 8 hours and post-operative day 1 morning and post-operative day 1 afternoon).

After playing around, I created a decent graph, starting from this code:

```
plot <-- ggplot(data=rescue, aes(Measurement, Percentage, color=factor(Group))) + geom_line()
```

With several commands, I adjusted the graph to my liking and I have this:
[image]

I would like to replace 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 on the `x-axis` with the labels `1 hour`, `4 hours`, `8 hours`, `POD1 Morning` and `POD1 Afternoon`.

I searched this site and google and came up with this code:

```
plot1 <-- plot + scale_x_discrete(labels=c("1"="1 hour", "2"="4 hours", "3"="8 hours", "4"="POD1 Morning", "5"="POD1 Afternoon"))
```

I also tried `levels=c(1,2,3,4,5)` and `labels=c("1 hour", "4 hours", etc)` but
all I get is an empty `x-axis`, no new labels. I cannot seem to make it work. In another post I read the advice to use `xaxt="n"`, but I cannot get that to work with `ggplot2`.

Could anyone please help me?
Thank you so much!

Comment: You've to change the name of the variable who contents the timepoints before to use ggplot. If I've an overview of your data.frame or juste the head of data (rescue), I could help you more. ;-)

Comment: Based on your plot, my guess is that your x axis is *continuous* not discrete.  Try `scale_x_continuous`.

Comment: @PysNLove Thanks for your reply. I've just now been able to continue working on this project. If I change the name of the variable before using ggplot, the graph doesn't show correctly (the lines don't follow the same pattern). I was able to get the correct graph by using `scale_x_continuous` as suggested by aosmith.

Comment: @aosmith Thank you, I was able to make it work with using `scale_x_continuous`!

Answer (score 2):

Consider using *breaks* in [`scale_x_discrete()`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ggplot2/docs/scale_discrete)

```
plot <- ggplot(data=rescue, aes(Measurement, Percentage, color=factor(Group))) + 
        geom_line() +  
        scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                labels=c("1 hour", "4 hours", "8 Hours", "POD1 Morning", "POD1 Afternoon"))
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! When I used _breaks_ in `scale_x_discrete` the x-axis showed up empty again. I could make it work with `scale_x_continuous` as suggested by aosmith

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to apply a discrete axis to a continues variable (Measurement). The fix would be to turn Measurement into factors:

`plot <-- ggplot(data=rescue, aes(factor(Measurement), Percentage, color=factor(Group))) + geom_line()`

And you'll probably want to manually change the label by adding on

`+ labs(x = 'Measurement')`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I turned Measurement into factors, no lines showed up in my graph. I got the error message 'Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?' I'm not very familiar with coding yet, but my guess is that this error showed because I have only imported an excel file with the mean percentage for each group at each measurement (so there is only one observation per time point per group). Using the `scale_x_continuous` the x-axis tick marks showed up correctly.